# What factors affect the speed of an Android application?

Tags: java, android

I wrote a method in java that consists of a O(n) single loop that creates an ArrayList and adds elements to it, and takes a couple seconds to process ~10000 entries. However, my android application takes 1 to 2 minutes to perform the same task. I'm not asking for how to solve that problem in particular, it's just what prompted the question in my mind: what factors makes java code run slower on an android than my laptop?

Specifically:

- Is the processing power of the Android lower?
- Is it because the android handles tasks differently?
- What steps can be taken to make an app more time-efficient, especially in processing large amounts of data?

Answer (score 2):

Processor type and design (including depth of instruction pipeline, caches, and data locality - probably [ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) vs [Intel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86)), system libraries, memory bandwidth, Operating System and run-time environment implementation (one being optimized for speed, and one for space / power savings).

These are engineering trade-offs required to fit the device in your pocket with an internal screen and an internal power supply.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it probably is. A phone needs a more power saving and slower processor.
2. No, since both phone and laptop run (almost) identical JREs there shouldn't be a difference. If you'd install Android on your PC and would execute the smae code it would run as fast as under windows. 
   3.I can only help you make the code more time efficent if you post it. Note that even small improvements cann add up if the code is executed 10000 times.

Comment: Your second point is completely incorrect. Desktop code will usually run in a standard JRE (Java Runtime) while Android runs a custom runtime called Dalvik (and in the future ART - Android Runtime). This can also have a dramatic impact on execution speed as they are tailored to different design goals.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25575371/1326821) given by [@Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch)  is 100% correct and covers everything that has an effect on execution speed.

However, I think it is very important to stress the software differences and how the runtime implentation on Android is completely different than the one usually used on the desktop.

On the desktop, Java code is compiled to **java bytecode** which is then executed by a [Java Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine). This VM is usually optimized for speed on whatever hardware and operating system your desktop is running.

On the Android side the same Java code is also compiled to **bytecode**, but it is very different and is executed by the Android specific [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) runtime, which is (generally) optimized for efficiency (power saving, etc) instead of pure speed.

The next version of Android (L) is set to replace this runtime with a slightly more speed oriented verion called [ART (Android Runtime)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime) - it will do this by using Ahead-Of-Time (AOT) compiling instead of Just-In-Time (JIT), which should speed up execution.

Considering all of this it might be argued that given the exact same hardware there might still be a difference in execution speed between desktop and Android. And in fact the same can be said for executiong the same Java code on different desktop operating systems (Windows vs Linux vs OSX) and different Java VMs.

The bottom line is that even though hardware plays the biggest part in your execution speed, the runtime environment has an very significant impact on how fast your code executes.